# CloudFormation to Configure API Gateway Method to use Cognito Authorizer

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to define API Gateway resources using CloudFormation. Specifically, I'm attempting to create a template for an API Gateway Resource Method that authenticates using Cognito. I've created the Authorizer, and using the console I can perform this configuration without issue (see image attached). I just can't find a way to specify the API method request authorization using the Cognito user pool. It's driving me crazy. As far as I can see, no documentation covers this.

Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so, how to do it? I realize I can achieve this using Swagger but I'm not looking forward to re-defining all of my API Gateway resources in Swagger vs. CloudFormation.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Method Authorization Configuration in Console]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a code sample handy, but here's what you will need to do:

1) Add an [Authorizer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-authorizer.html) resource to your template with type "COGNITO_USER_POOLS",

2) Set the authorizerId on the API [method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-method.html) resource to the ID reference from the authorizer. Set the authorizationType on the method to "COGNITO_USER_POOLS"

As for the user pools themselves, you will need to use custom resources, at least until official support is released. There are several open-source implementations out there that you could use (here's one example: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-api-gateway-developer-portal/tree/7d0d1e56d54e9775ee2d18907ebdf1db9dafcc06/lambdas/cognito-cloudformation-custom-resource)

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help. I'm pretty sure this is exactly what I need. Just doing some testing before I mark this correct.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using SAM then you set the pool as a global default and mark the functions you don't want to be authenticated.

```
  MyApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      Cors: "'*'"
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: MyCognitoAuthorizer
        Authorizers:
          MyCognitoAuthorizer:
            UserPoolArn: !GetAtt MyCognitoUserPool.Arn

  MyFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./src
      Handler: lambda.handler
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      Events:
        Root:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref MyApi
            Path: /
            Method: GET

  MyCognitoUserPool:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
    Properties:
      UserPoolName: !Ref CognitoUserPoolName
      Policies:
        PasswordPolicy:
          MinimumLength: 8
      UsernameAttributes:
        - email
      Schema:
        - AttributeDataType: String
          Name: email
          Required: false

  MyCognitoUserPoolClient:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient
    Properties:
      UserPoolId: !Ref MyCognitoUserPool
      ClientName: !Ref CognitoUserPoolClientName
      GenerateSecret: false
```

For functions you don't want to be behind cognito. Define in the events section of the AWS::Serverless::Function definition.

```
Events:
        Root:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref MyApi
            Path: /
            Method: GET
            Auth:
              Authorizer: 'NONE'
```

Use the AWS Sam template documentation rather than the cloudformation definitions.